# Changing a data column from varchar(max) to nvarchar(max) in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to change the data type in a SQL Server 2008 table from varchar(max) to nvarchar(max).  This table has data in it.  Is there a way to change the data type without losing the data?

Answer (score 17):

You can just use standard syntax to alter the table:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table ALTER COLUMN some_column nvarchar(max)
```

You will probably want to rebuild any indices however, to make sure they work as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Another option to minimize disruption (since I don't believe the `ALTER COLUMN` will occur online), is:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table ADD new_column NVARCHAR(MAX); -- metadata operation
```

Now you can update the data in waves/batches/transactions instead of applying the change to the whole table in one long transaction. When you're satisfied that the data is copied over, you can drop the old column, rename the new one, and re-create any affected indexes (your MAX column can't be in the key of any index, but you might have inadvertently put it into an INCLUDE definition - if that is the case you should question that anyway).

You'll still want to rebuild all indexes to reclaim the now unused space (which you can do online if you're using Enterprise Edition).

Answer (score 2):

Always take a backup so no matter what happens you can go back to the way things were.

With that said changing from `varchar(max)` to `nvarchar(max)` should not lose data.

*Side note:* you might have concerns if you were changing in the other direction  `nvarchar(max)` to `varchar(max)`   as the process would have to convert extended characters if any were present.

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL Server 2016, this can now be an ONLINE operation

[SQL 2016 ALTER COLUMN online](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4749/sql-server-2016-online-alter-column-operation/)